# Сокет открыт на несколько IP-адресов

Tags: c++, boost

Возможно ли создать сокет, который будет принимать сообщения на несколько своих IP-адресов? Что я имею в виду:

IP-адреса машины:

1. 127.0.0.1
2. 192.168.0.108
3. 33.87.11.10

И при вызове `socket.receive_from(asio::buffer(data, max_length), sender_endpoint);` Будет принимать сообщения идущие на любой из адресов из списка.

В данный момент инициализирую сокет следующим образом:

```
string IP; int port;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
const udp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(IP), port);
udp::socket socket(args.io_service, ep);
```

**UPDATE1** Мне не надо на все локальные адреса. Только те, которые я задаю списком.

Comment: Чтобы принимать на все локальные адреса откройте сокет на 0.0.0.0

Comment: Как вариант - используйте несколько сокетов, каждый сбиндиный на нужный локальный адрес.

Comment: @Outtruder ваш комментарий должен быть ответом

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это не ответ.

Comment: это именно что ответ. Неверный, но ответ, а не комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы принимать на все локальные адреса откройте сокет на 0.0.0.0

Если же вам надо принимать соединения не на все адреса - а на адреса из некоторого списка, то такое сделать в рамках Berkley Sockets и их наследников - невозможно.

Обойти подобное ограничение можно двумя способами.

### Вариант 1.

Создать по сокету на каждый адрес.

### Вариант 2.

Прослушивать все адреса, но ограничить входящие пакеты при помощи системного файервола.

Comment: Вариант 3: прослушивать все адреса, но отбрасывать соединения с "левых" адресов в самом приложении.